# header location parameter not appearing in url

Tags: php, parameters, header, location

I am using Header() to go to another page and pass a parameter in the URL. It was working but now, for some reason, the parameter does not appear in the URL.

Here is the code:

```
echo $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]?uuid=$uuid";
header('Location:'.$actual_link);
exit;
```

This is the result of the `echo $actual_link`:

```
http://creatives.com/test/quiz-result?uuid=1efbe46985960aa96fd991a3cfc4dff4
```

This is what appears in the URL of the browser (Google Chrome)

http://creatives.com/test/quiz-result

I am baffled.

All thoughts welcome.

Comment: Opera doesn't display query params, if you haven't got focus on the location field.  I wonder if it's something akin to that, what's your Chrome version?  Looks okay to me in Chromium 48.

Comment: Please note that you can't use `header(...)` after `echo`. Are you doing that in production code too?

Comment: Nope, its not the browser. I can copy and paste the address into the address bar and it works fine. Not using echo in the production code, have taken it and the problem still persists. Weird!